# What is the Lewis dot diagram for molybdenum and cerium?

Tags: lewis-structure

How do I draw a Lewis diagram for $\ce{Mo}$ and $\ce{Ce}$?
 I am a bit confused since they are transition metals.
**Attempt**
The outer electron configuration for $\ce{Mo}$ is $\ce{5s^1 4d^5}$. The number of valence electrons would be 6 if I am correct. Wouldn't the Lewis dot structure look like the one for group 6A elements with six dots?

**EDIT**: I spoke to my lecturer, he said I have to do research and draw the Lewis dot diagram of Mo and Ce. My textbook says that transition metals have incompletely filled inner shells, and that generally we cannot write simple Lewis dot symbols for them. Yet, my lecturer said it would be similar to other elements. I am very confused!

Comment: From what I gather from the definition of Lewis dot structures from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_structure) they exist for bonded atoms or compounds. Not for single atoms. Do you mean the electronic configuration instead?

Comment: I spoke to my lecturer, he said I have to do research and draw the Lewis dot diagram of Mo and Ce. My textbook says that transition metals have incompletely filled inner shells, and that generally we cannot write simple Lewis dot symbols for them. Yet, my lecturer said it would be similar to other elements. I am very confused!